# Ms-Access SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need some guidance on how to write a query in Ms-Access which will pull all the records based on the PublishedDate but with-in the expiry date. For instance, my table carries 3 columns EventTitle, PublishDate, ExpiryDate with values Title1, 2/22/2012, 3/28/2012.

Now the 1st record will only appear on 22-Feb-2012 until 28-Mar-2012. The query which I used drops the record once the current date changes from 22-Feb to 23-Feb.

I tried using the below script

```
SELECT top 1 Title, ExpiryDate 
FROM Table1 
WHERE (((PublishDate)=Date() 
Or (PublishDate)<=[ExpiryDate]) 
AND ((ExpiryDate)>=Date())) 
ORDER BY ExpiryDate ASC
```

Comment: Please show us a brief representative sample of data from Table1.  Then show us the results you want based on that sample data.

Comment: Thanks Hansup, it looks like the issue seems resolved. I am doing the testing now with different scenarios. Anyways, thanks again for your note..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want this:

```
SELECT top 1 Title, ExpiryDate  
FROM Table1  
WHERE PublishDate<=Date() 
AND ExpiryDate>=Date() 
ORDER BY ExpiryDate ASC
```

Comment: Hi Robert, thank for your reply. Since PublishDate will not always be equal to current date so it will not return any value. For example., PublishDate in table is 22-Feb but the current date is 23-Feb, so in that case, the query will fail.

Comment: OK.  So describe in plain English what you want the conditions to be.  Do you want the publish date to be less than the current date?

Comment: Hi Robert, after doing little tweaking in the SQL you provided to PublishDate <= Date() AND ExpiryDate >= Date(), I believe I am getting the result as desired. Thanks very much for your help.